# Timespan to display just the days, without hrs, min, and sec

Tags: vb.net, timespan, days

Timespan to display just the days, without hrs, min, and sec.

my time span is coming like 30.00:00:00 for 39 days. please help in vb.net code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [TimeSpan documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Assuming you start with this:

```
' Define an interval of 3 days, 16+ hours. 
Dim interval As New TimeSpan(3, 16, 42, 45, 750) 
Console.WriteLine(interval.Days())
Console.WriteLine(interval.ToString("dddd"))
```

You have two options for displaying time in days. The first is:

```
Console.WriteLine(interval.Days())
```

or you can format your time in the ToString function:

```
Console.WriteLine(interval.ToString("dddd"))
```

You would need to add as many `d`s as you are expecting to display or you will get an error.